# Bundler with Capistrano doesn't generate a binary for DelayedJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, delayed-job, capistrano3

I'm using Bundler for a Rails app deployed by Capistrano. I'm trying to add the DelayedJob gem, but the bin/delayed_job file is missing from the remote server after I do a deploy. It exists on my local machine.

I tried manually creating it with `bundle binstubs delayed_job` but it fails with: `There are no executables for the gem delayed_job.`

What am I missing here?

The gems in question are: Bundler 1.3.5, Capistrano 3.1.0, DelayedJob 4.0.0, Rails 4.0.2

EDIT: Here is my full Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/WuE3eJrj

Comment: And your `Gemfile`...?

Comment: @UriAgassi I uploaded the Gemfile.

Comment: does `bundle install` pass correctly on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, everything else is working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to include the `gem "daemons"`, according to the documentation:

> To do so, add gem "daemons" to your Gemfile and make sure you've run rails generate delayed_job.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#running-jobs

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue. The delayed_job binstub is not generated with bundler but with a rails generator. Prevent the bin directory from being symlinked during capistrano deploy. Change config/deploy.rb from this:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

to

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

Then i regenerated all binstubs locally using bundler

```
bundle install --binstubs
```

Now i ran the delayed_job generator

```
bundle exec rails g delayed_job
```

Check everything in and deploy again.