# Rails 4.2 ActiveJob: Every adapter results in PhusionPassenger error: Could not find [gem] in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, rails-activejob

I'm trying to implement asynchronous email processing with Rails 4.2's ActiveJob API. So far I've tried using two of the supported adapters: Sucker Punch and Delayed Job, and I get the same problem with each.

Things seem to work correctly in development. However, after deploying to the staging server and trying to load the website in my browser, I get the purple PhusionPassenger error screen with this error:

```
Could not find delayed_job-4.0.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

The above is for when I tried Delayed Job. My gem setup looks like this:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

# Gemfile.lock
    delayed_job (4.0.6)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    delayed_job_active_record (4.0.3)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      delayed_job (>= 3.0, < 4.1)
```

When I tried Sucker Punch, the PhusionPassenger error was the same except the gem that supposedly couldn't be found in any sources was `hitimes`, which is a dependency of `celluloid`, which is itself a dependency of `sucker_punch`.

I initially thought the problem was with Sucker Punch. After installing the Hitimes gem on my staging server and still getting the error, I decided to switch to Delayed Job, and now I'm getting pretty much the same problem, so I'm guessing there's some more low-level problem but I am not sure what it could be. I've also tried updating bundler on the staging server, but no dice.

Thanks in advance for any help!

***EDIT***

I did some more poking around on the Delayed Job github and found this command `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job restart`. When I tried to run `RAILS_ENV=staging bin/delayed_job restart` on my staging server I was alerted to the absence of a delayed_job binstub in my `bin/` directory. Looking back at my local development environment, I do see that `bin/delayed_job` exists and can run `bin/delayed_job restart` successfully. Could this lack of a binstub in staging be contributing to the problem? If so, why wouldn't that binstub have been created correctly? I am pretty sure that my capistrano deploy process uses `bundle exec bundle install --binstubs`.

**EDIT 2**

Through some steps outlined below I was able to get delayed_job to appear in my bin/ in staging. I also tried adding the "daemons" gem per a suggestion on the Delayed Job GitHub, but still getting the same error, now about "daemons" rather than "delayed_job" itself.

Comment: Are you sure that passenger is using the correct ruby?

Comment: I'm not sure. Unfortunately I also don't (currently) have the sysadmin knowledge to check which ruby passenger is using or change it. However, I can say that my base rails4 branch with no activejob adapter deploys and runs fine on the staging server. Also, I'm going to add some more information that I've gleaned related to binstubs that may or may not be helpful

Comment: no, but I do use rbenv

Comment: Do you have multiple ruby versions? Your app runs in a other version different of the default.?

Comment: the only ruby that is installed by rbenv is 2.2.0. so there's that and 'system'

Comment: How aré you using pssenger? Stand alone or with apache?

Comment: I'm using it with nginx.

Comment: So, you start passenger with passenger start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not with ActiveJob adapters, but with *any* gem that I tried to install and use in staging after doing the Rails 4 upgrade. I had installed rbenv on the staging server and added 2.2.0 as the global ruby, but Passenger was still looking for gems associated with the system ruby (1.9.3).

Answer (score 0):

It could well be the absence of your binstub, which can be fixed:

There was an 'issue' with capistrano-bundler, in that it would try to generate its own bin stubs, rather than taking them from the committed git repo. This has since been fixed, but can be seen in this issue:
https://github.com/capistrano/bundler/issues/45

You can force the committed binstub to be used by removing bin from your linked dirs so:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('bin', 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache' ...
```

becomes:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache' ...
```

and also setting

```
set :bundle_binstubs, nil
```

Or upgrading your cap-bundler gem.

Comment: I think I'm following you but am still not quite there. I upgrade capistrano-bundler to 1.1.4, redeployed, still don't have  bin/delayed_job. Then I ran `bundler binstubs delayed_job` and got `"There are no executables for the gem delayed_job."` Do I still need to do everything you listed above?

Comment: Also, I found the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659507/bundler-with-capistrano-doesnt-generate-a-binary-for-delayedjob. One person added the "daemons" gem and another did ore or less what you've listed above. If the above works, though, and was added in the PR you linked too, not sure why I'm still having the prob after upgrading

Comment: I tried adding daemons and now i'm just getting "Could not find daemons-1.1.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)" as my PhusionPasseneger error